# Prove sum of products of Hermitian matrices to be Hermitian

Tags: matrices, quantum-mechanics, hermitian-matrices

A given problem states:

> If $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian matrices, prove that $(AB+BA)$ is Hermitian.

Because the sum of Hermitian matrices is known to be Hermitian, the problem seems to me to boil down to proving that the products $AB$ and $BA$ are Hermitian. But this isn't necessarily so, unless $AB = BA$.

This problem is part of a course in quantum mechanics, and my attempt goes something like this:
$$
\int\psi^*(AB+BA)\psi \mathop{dr}  =  \int\psi^*AB\psi \mathop{dr}+\int\psi^*BA\psi \mathop{dr}\\
$$
At this point I suspect one should use the properties of $A$ and $B$ to get to the answer
$$
\int(AB+BA)^*\psi^*\psi \mathop{dr}
$$

Any clarification would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(AB+BA)^\ast = (AB)^\ast + (BA)^\ast = B^\ast A^\ast + A^\ast B^\ast = BA+AB = AB+BA$.

Individually $AB$ and $BA$ are not Hermitian, but $AB+BA$ is.